# Access argument passed to BackgroundWorker even if there is an Exception?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

**Short Version**

How do I access the argument passed to the `BackgroundWorker` in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event, if there is an exception raised?

**Longer Version**

I am using a `BackgroundWorker` component in my application. At application launch, I query a database to get a list of messages that are unsent. Then using a GSM Modem (inside background worker) I send messages one by one.

Now as soon as I decide to send a message, I add it to a list called **CurrentlyHandledMessages**. This is ensure that 2 modems won't send the same message.

Now I pass the ID of the message to the `BackgroundWorker` as an argument and it sends the message, and the `RunWorkerCompleted` event is raised and I remove the ID from the **CurrentlyHandledMessages** list. I pass the result as a Tuple.

```
e.Result = new Tuple<int, String>(idToHandle, response);
```

This is working fine if there was no exception.

However, I cannot see how I can get the argument passed to the `BackgroundWorker` if there is an exception raised. Because in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event, I want to remove the id no matter what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built in way of getting the argument that was passed (in this case the ID). You'll need to pass it on your own. I would recommend simply passing it all the time, regardless of an exception, so imagine something like this inside of the `DoWork` handler:

```
string response;

try
{
    ...

    response = "something";
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    response = e.ToString();
}
finally
{
    e.Result = new Tuple<int, string>((int)e.Argument, response);
}
```

and so now, regardless of the outcome, you're going to get that ID into the `RunWorkerCompleted` handler.

Comment: If I catch the exception and no re-throw it, will it still be available in the `e.Error` in  `RunWorkerCompleted` event?

Comment: @RanhiruCooray, good question and I don't know, but it's safe to rethrow it too. Leave everything else the same and rethrow because that will still hit the finally.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // do the work
    }
    catch (Exception ex) // on error 
    {
        e.Error = ex;
        e.Result = "set the data here";
    }
}
```

on complete event

> Check for e.Error first, then e.Cancelled and lastly e.Result

Answer (score 1):

You can pass information via the [Error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.asynccompletedeventargs.error.aspx) property of [RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.runworkercompletedeventargs.aspx).

You need to handle exception and throw custom exception with `Id` and `Response`

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted(v=vs.85).aspx)

> Your RunWorkerCompleted event handler should always check the
>   AsyncCompletedEventArgs.Error and AsyncCompletedEventArgs.Cancelled
>   properties before accessing the RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs.Result
>   property. If an exception was raised or if the operation was canceled,
>   accessing the RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs.Result property raises an
>   exception.

Answer (score 0):

Just derive from BackgroundWorker and implement a required property:

```
public class CustomBackgroundWorker : BackgroundWorker
{
    public object Argument { get; private set; }

    protected override void OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Argument = e.Argument;
        base.OnDoWork(e);
    }
}
```

Then access it from RunWorkerCopmleted and other events as follows:

```
private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    object originalArgument = ((CustomBackgroundWorker)sender).Argument;

    // The rest of the stuff
    if (e.Cancelled) { ... }
    if (e.Error) {...}
    ...
}
```

The error handling semantics is left intact